# Downloading file doesn't work correctly angular , node js

Tags: javascript, angular

I am developping node js , angular 5 application.
I have a functionality to download files.My code works for small files but for large Files like .zip with 2gb i can download them but after a long time  and i can 't see download progress bar immediatly when i click on download ( isee it after the download starts) and sometimes my navigator crashes.
this my backend code:

```
downloadFile(req, res) {

log.info("Begin method 'download  file' ");
var file = req.body;

return DB.sequelize.transaction({ isolationLevel: DB.sequelize.Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.READ_UNCOMMITTED }, (t) => {
    const filePath = 'C:\Users\a\files';
    res.sendFile(resolve(filePath));
    log.info("End method 'download file' ");
}).then((result) => {
        // Transaction has been committed
    }).catch((err) => {
        log.error(err);
        // Transaction has been rolled back
    });
 }
```

This is my service on the Frontend side:

```
  downloadFile(file): Observable<Blob> {
return this.http.post(`${this.Url}/download`, file, { responseType: 'blob'}) }
```

This is my component Fonctionnality:

```
downloadFile(file) {
this.dataService.downloadFile(file).subscribe(data => {
    saveAs(data, file.name);
})
}
```

Thank you in advance